# How to improve the performance of an alpha-beta minimax method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, recursion, artificial-intelligence, chess, minimax

I’ve been a programming student for about six months. I’d been wanting to write a chess game since a long time, and finally made it. I’m very happy with the result, however, there’s a point I don’t know how to address. The AI is based on an alpha-beta pruning `#minimax` method that chooses the best move on the basis of the best possible outcome for the current player, with a `depth` default value of 3, which means the computer can think ahead 3 turns. The computer does choose the correct move, but the method in its current implementation is very slow.

`#provisional` makes and 'unmakes' a possible `move`, and returns the value returned from the code block. The evaluation function `#evaluate` is very simple, it’s just a sum of the material value of the pieces and their location values according to how are they placed on the board.

I’d really appreciate some light here, as I don’t know how to get a faster version of this method.
Thank you so much for your time.

This is the method:

```rb
  def minimax(move, depth, alpha, beta, maximizing_player)
    return board.evaluate if depth.zero?

    board.provisional(move, color) do
      if maximizing_player
        best_minimizing_evaluation = Float::INFINITY

        board.generate_moves(:black).each do |possible_move|
          evaluation = minimax(possible_move, depth - 1, alpha, beta, false)
          best_minimizing_evaluation = [best_minimizing_evaluation, evaluation].min
          beta = [beta, evaluation].min
          break if beta <= alpha
        end

        best_minimizing_evaluation
      else
        best_maximizing_evaluation = -Float::INFINITY

        board.generate_moves(:white).each do |possible_move|
          evaluation = minimax(possible_move, depth - 1, alpha, beta, true)
          best_maximizing_evaluation = [best_maximizing_evaluation, evaluation].max
          alpha = [alpha, evaluation].max
          break if beta <= alpha
        end

        best_maximizing_evaluation
      end
    end
  end
```

With an initial `depth` value of 3, it takes between 15 and 50 seconds for the method to resolve and return the chosen move; this is a lot, and makes the game barely enjoyable. Changing the `depth` value to 2, the times are more reasonable, being about a third of the previous times, but I’d really like to keep the `depth` at 3. With a depth of 1, of course, it takes less than a second.

I realize that some improvements can be made, however, I don’t know how to:

- Will a negamax version of this method significantly  improve its performance?
- I’m aware of the Tail Recursion Optimization, however, is it possible in this case? I don’t know if it is a tree-generating method like this.
- I’ve been told that pre-sorting the moves somehow before they are evaluated can improve the performance in alpha-beta minimaxes, but, how can I sort the moves? I can’t sort them by the immediate outcome, because, for instance, sometimes it’s worth to sacrifice a piece to win a better position. I could sort them by best possible outcome in 2 turns... but then I'd be computing twice, once for the sorting of the moves, and once for the actual move evaluation.
- It's implementing a transposition table worth it? I mean, there are tons of potential positions, and they easy can make a file really big. For example, in a day, the program generated a 100 MB text file, and I didn't notice a huge performance improvement, as the computer don't always makes the same moves, and neither do I. The different position for a chess game are innumerable, unlike in a game like Tic Tac Toe.

Thank you so much.

Comment: How are you encoding your board and moves? What methods are you using to generate moves?

Comment: Hi, the board is represented by a 2d array: an array of size 8 containing 8 subarrays, each subarray of size 8; this allows me to access each square by `board[row][column]`. Each square contains either a `Piece` object or an `EmptySquare` object. To generate moves, there's a `Piece#available_moves` that looks like this: (for example. for the `Bishop` piece:

Comment: https://github.com/lucsorr/sapphire-chess/blob/main/lib/sapphire-chess/movement_rules/move_slide_pattern.rb

Comment: Each move is encoded as an array of two subarrays: i.e.: `[[1, 1], [1, 2]]`, in which the first subarray represents the piece's current location, and the second the targeted square.

Comment: This is probably where I would start if you are looking for speed (and hence depth) improvements. Due to the size of the search space, it is important that board encoding, move encoding, and move generation is as efficient as possible. If you want a deep search, you can't afford to waste time by constructing and destroying objects that represent the pieces.

Comment: I would suggest moving to a bitboard approach, where you use unsigned 64-bit ints to represent the piece positions (see: https://www.chessprogramming.org/Bitboards), the information of any move can be encoded in 14 bits (see: https://www.chessprogramming.org/Encoding_Moves). Moves can be generated very quickly using these representations by taking advantage of bitwise operators.

Comment: Although, if you are not really interested in the low level details of move generation, and would rather focus on making an AI to play against, I would recommend using an existing optimised move generator (e.g. the one used for Stockfish https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish). Having that in place would allow you to make more progress on the AI side of things.

Comment: Thank you so so much! I'm going to start by trying the low level approach, and see where  that path leads me.